# MySQL Fetch Array doubt

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I´m fetching my database for images to create a gallery. Every row appear inside a `<li>`. My question is, is it possible, that the first `<li>` have a class (for example, `"visible"`), and all the other `<li>` have a class named `"hidden"`. So the first `$row` would have a different class than the following...
Hope I made myself clear!
Thanks

Comment: Why was this voted down?  And would someone please fix the title, so that it's a better representation of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like

```
$visible = true;

while(...) {

     if($visible) {
         echo "<li class='visible'>";
     else {
         echo "<li class='hidden'>";
     }
     $visible = false; // Every loop sets it to false, which after the first one will make no difference.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well thats easy! Just track the row number, if it is the first row then echo out class="visible" else class='hidden"

Answer (score 2):

It can be done *more shortlier* like this:

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<li class="' . (($i == 1) ? 'visible' : 'hidden') . '">';
    $i++;
}
```